# Выставление бита в единицу в QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt

Через последовательный порт я получаю массив байтов. Последние 2 байта являются корректировочными. Для примера, если 5-й бит в корректировочном байте 1, то 1-й бит в 5 байте тоже должен выставляться в 1. Результат должен выводиться в QLineEdit в десятичном представлении. Как это лучше сделать?

Пытался сделать следующее:

```
ui->data1->setText(tr("%1").arg(int([arr[]](){if(arr[12] & (1<<5)){arr[4] | 128}}));
```

ошибка

```
expected ',' or ']' in lambda capture list
```

И так:

```
if(arr[12] & (1<<5))
    {
        arr[4] = arr[4] | 128;
    }

ui->data1->setText(tr("%1").arg(int(arr[4])));
```

Компилируется, но не работает, первый бит всё равно 0.

Comment: В Вашем странном коде, Вы пытаетесь в лямбду передать массив в виде `arr[]` - так точно нельзя, не зависимо от того, что такое arr. Я бы код вначале проверил хотя бы отладчиком, заходит ли оно в условие. Также чувствую, что тут может быть проблема с тем, что QByteArray хранит char, а он знаковый.

Comment: в boost есть [адаптер](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) на этот случай. Можно скормить ему begin и end вашего QByteArray, а потом бегать по битам, как по обычному массиву